# Find a smart way to deal with Null value. Operator override possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a big Tag Formula Table, a numeric data table In SQL Server 2008 database. The Formula table is like

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Formula VARCHAR(MAX), -- Nullable.
```

Rules:

1. Every Tag has an entry in Formula table
2. If the Formula is not null, that means there is no value in the data table
3. If the Formula is null, that means the data value is coming from the data table. In this case I call it a 'value' tag.
4. In case of 2, the Formula may be something like T(123) + T(456), but there will never be like T(T(234)+T(456)). The ID part in T(ID) must be a constant number. The formula could be +-*/(), and may have some SQL functions.

The data table is like

```
DATE SMALLDATETIME PRIMARY KEY, -- 2019-06-01
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,             -- Which ID this value belongs to
VALUE FLOAT                     -- Not Nullable
```

Data table rules

1. Not all the value tag has it's value entry in Data Table, based on the date.
2. DATE and ID are the primary key

So I wrote a func ExtractTags, take a varchar(max), and return 2 values raw tags and extracted formula.

Example:

Input:

```
    'T(234) As T234, T(567) As T567'
```

Output:

```
RawTag:
    '[1],[3],[2],[6],[8],[10],[13],[467]'
ExtractedTags:
    '(([1] + [2]) * ([3] + [6]) - [8]) As T234, ([10] + [13] + [467]) As T567'
```

The dynamic SQL I generated will looks like

```
SELECT DATE, (([1] + [2]) * ([3] + [6]) - [8]) As T234, ([10] + [13] + [467]) As T567
FROM (SELECT N.DATE, N.Value, N.ID 
     FROM NumericData AS N 
         Where N.DATE BETWEEN '2019-05-01' And '2019-05-3'
) 
x PIVOT (
    MAX(Value) for ID in ([1],[3],[2],[6],[8],[10],[13],[467])
) p
```

Then based on this 2 value I can create a dynamic SQL, which will pivot on the datatable, and then get the value of it, and then calculate the result.

Issue:

- Because some of the value could have no entry at a certain date, so it may shows Null. for example, ([10] + [13] + [467]) ==> T567. if [467] has no value, then the result is null. In this case, I want to ignore the value of [467], or deal it as 0.
- If I change all the [xxx] to IsNull([xxx], 0), another problem will raise: say [10], [13] and [467] are all null, then I want to see T567 as Null.
- I am thinking to create my own function SUMIFNOTNULL(a,b) ==> Only returns null if both a and b are null, otherwise deal null as 0.
- But the problem is a) I am not allow to change the Formula table, and
  it may keep growing. b) Even if I can, it will be huge work to change
  all the formulas (more than 10,000 records)

Example of an output

If I use IsNull([xxx],0) I will see

```
DATE      |  T234   |  T567
----------+---------+---------
2019-05-01|  0      |  0
2019-05-02| 123.5   |  0
2019-05-03| 456.5   |  567.5
```

If I don't use IsNull([xxx],0) I will see

```
DATE      |  T234   |  T567
----------+---------+---------
2019-05-01| NULL    |  NULL
2019-05-02| 123.5   |  NULL
2019-05-03| 456.5   |  567.5
```

I really want to see

```
DATE      |  T234   |  T567
----------+---------+---------
2019-05-01|  0      |  NULL
2019-05-02| 123.5   |  0
2019-05-03| 456.5   |  567.5
```

Any good idea to solve this problem? Can SQL Server override the '+' operator?

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help.  Also, what is `INT*`?

Comment: I want to indicate it is the primary key. I change it to be easier to understood

Comment: . . No, SQL Server does not offer a way to override built-in operators.

Comment: Can I create my own operator in SQL?

Comment: Actually, overriding + is not enough. I need to override all of them +-*/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out. I create another function called 'SmartFormula', which will deal with this. Here is the code.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'SmartFormula') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION SmartFormula
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SmartFormula 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Formula VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT
    DECLARE @PEND INT
    DECLARE @RawTag VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @RawTags VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Field  VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FldStart INT
    DECLARE @FldEnd INT

    SET @RESULT = ''
    SET @FldEnd = 0
    SET @FldStart = 1

    WHILE @FldStart < LEN(@Formula)
    BEGIN
        SET @FldEnd = CHARINDEX(',', @Formula, @FldStart)
        IF @FldEnd = 0 SET @FldEnd = LEN(@Formula)
        SET @Field = SUBSTRING(@Formula, @FldStart, @FldEnd - @FldStart + 1)
        SET @FldStart = @FldEnd + 1

        SET @RawTags = '';
        SET @POS = CHARINDEX('[', @Field, 1);
        WHILE @POS <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @PEND = CHARINDEX(']', @Field, @POS);
            IF @PEND = 0 BREAK;
            SET @RawTag = SUBSTRING(@Field, @POS, @PEND - @POS + 1)
            IF CHARINDEX(@RawTag, @RawTags, 1) = 0  --Not in the tags yet
            BEGIN
                IF LEN(@RawTags) > 0
                    SET @RawTags = @RawTags + ' AND ' + @RawTag + ' Is NULL';
                ELSE
                    SET @RawTags = @RawTag + ' Is NULL';
            END
            SET @POS = CHARINDEX('[', @Field, @PEND + 1);
        END
        IF LEN(@RawTags) > 0
        BEGIN
            SEt @Field = REPLACE(@Field, 'AS', 'END AS')
            SET @Field = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Field, '[', 'ISNULL(['),']','],0)')
            SET @RESULT = @RESULT + 'CASE WHEN ' + @RawTags + ' THEN NULL ELSE ' + @Field
        END
    END
    RETURN @RESULT
END
GO
```

TEST

```
    SELECT SmartFormula('([123] + [456]) / [235] As T12,([222] - [12345]) As T222')
```

OUTPUT

```
CASE WHEN [123] Is NULL AND [456] Is NULL AND [235] Is NULL THEN NULL ELSE (ISNULL([123],0) + ISNULL([456],0)) / ISNULL([235],0) END AS T12,CASE WHEN [222] Is NULL AND [12345] Is NULL THEN NULL ELSE (ISNULL([222],0) - ISNULL([12345],0)) END AS T222
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this using a `case` expression:

```
(case when [10] is not null or [13] is not null or [467] is not null
      then coalesce([10], 0) + coalesce([13], 0) + coalesce([467], 0)
 end)
```

However, I'm not sure how this fits into your processing structure.

I had thought that you might be able to convert `0` results back to `NULL`:

```
nullif(coalesce([10], 0) + coalesce([13], 0) + coalesce([467], 0), 0)
```

But apparently you can get legitimate zero values.

Comment: That works for sure, if there is just couple of formulas. The problem is I have more than 10,000 formulas. That is why I am thinking if I can override + operator, that will be great.

Comment: nullif(coalesce([10], 0) + coalesce([13], 0) + coalesce([467], 0), 0) won't work. It will always change 0 to null, which I only want to change 0 to null if [10], [13] and [467] are all null.